# Создание таблиц БД

Tags: база-данных

Пишу курсовой проект по базам данных. Во время написания у меня получилось 10 взаимосвязанных таблиц. Но у меня есть еще одна служебная таблица. Она никак не связана с темой предыдущих 10 таблиц, то есть признака для связи с ними нет.

Возможно ли при правильной проектировке БД, чтобы какая-то из таблиц не была связана ни с чем, а просто находилась сама по себе? Верно ли это с точки зрения правильного формирования БД? Если нет, то как исправить?

Comment: Если не связана, то зачем она тогда нужна и как вообще относится к теме предыдущих таблиц?

Comment: Она хранит некоторые флаги, которые мне нужны для выполнения операций в программе.

Comment: Если эти флаги постоянны, их количество и значения не изменяются, то можно их так и вписать в код программы в виде списка/словара/перечисления и т.п.

Comment: Если бы такая возможность была, я бы это сделал. Я спросил с точки зрения формирования бд это верно или нет ?

Comment: Абсолютно верно. Связи в БД должны отражать связи объектов в реальном мире. Так как настройки программы никак не связаны с какими либо другими данными, то и связей у таблицы быть не может